# How to put an HUD on top, reliably (esp over MFMailComposeViewController)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a little bit new at iOS and have inherited a project that uses a third-party HUD view that is semitransparent, self-dismisses after three seconds, etc.  It looks nice.  It grabs the active view and adds itself as a subview.

However, it doesn't seem to reliably pop up on top of the topmost window.  We occasionally navigate to other view controllers using presentViewController, and at one point we present a MFMailComposeViewController.  To resolve this I have painstakingly tracked the events of the application to remember which view is active and save a pointer to it (I know there should be a built-in way but like I said it doesnt seem reliable), and used that to call the third-part HUD.  This works okay except for when the MFMailComposeViewController is active, I don't seem to be able to pop anything over that.

Should I be able to pop something over an MFMailComposeViewController?  The application both (a) allows the user to email data and also (b) presents important alerts, and I really need to do both.

Thanks for any thoughts about this specific question and generally how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have to present a view on top of the topmost window I use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].

For example:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:hud];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this doesn't seem to work if MFMailComposeViewController is top view controller..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

AppDelegate *del = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[del.window addSubView:hud];